# Error pushing to github

Tags: git, github

With no apparent reason, my github repo is not accepting my pushes:

`git push origin master` throws a

```
remote: /data/github/current/lib/github/config/resque.rb:27: undefined method `constantize' for "GitHub::Jobs::WikiReceive":String (NoMethodError)
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/github/config/resque.rb:26:in `each'
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/github/config/resque.rb:26
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/rock_queue.rb:9:in `require'
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/rock_queue.rb:9
remote:     from hooks/post-receive:27:in `require'
remote:     from hooks/post-receive:27
```

I'm amazed, it's the first time github is failing me!

Have you experienced anything similar?

Comment: I'd contact GitHub for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem on their end -- see the [latest entry](http://status.github.com/) on their status page. (I got the same error when attempting a push about 10 minutes ago.)

Comment: Yep, I got nervous as a big deployment in our side was inminent. I later saw the blog entry :)

Answer (score 2):

Their post-receive hook is erroring. See the status page - http://status.github.com/

The hint is that, the errors have `remote` prepended. It means that the output and errors are coming from the remote hook on the github side.