# How do I synchronize a local remote branch with GitHub?

Tags: git, github

This might be a repost but I have no idea how to find my problem. Here's what happened: I wrote a commit and I pushed it to GitHub. It said

```
rkmba:project ryan$ git push origin 08-local:3.25.08
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 498 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /data/github/current/lib/github/config/resque.rb:27: undefined method `constantize' for "GitHub::Jobs::WikiReceive":String (NoMethodError)
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/github/config/resque.rb:26:in `each'
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/github/config/resque.rb:26
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/rock_queue.rb:9:in `require'
remote:     from /data/github/current/lib/rock_queue.rb:9
remote:     from hooks/post-receive:27:in `require'
remote:     from hooks/post-receive:27
To git@github.com:MyRepo/MyRepo.git
   46fd407..fbad9c6  08-local -> 3.25.08
```

Suffice it to say, this is weird to me! I don't normally get a call stack back when I do a push. Either way, the commit that I pushed up to GH is not appearing on the website and my team members cannot pull it, but I can't push it because Git believes everything is up to date. Is there a way for me to synchronize the commits in my origin/3.25.08 branch with github's branch so that I can push this commit? I cannot do a pull to update the branch because it says my branch is already up to date.

This also happens on master.

Comment: [GitHub is having problems right now](http://status.github.com/)

Comment: Yep looks like someone at GH is going to run my commit hook manually. Cannot answer my own question and mark as answered, sorry!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error pushing to github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036246/error-pushing-to-github)

Comment: Hi Ryan, this is very strange indeed! Can you please send an Email to GitHub Support (support@github.com) with these details so we can get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary problem on GitHub.com that has now been resolved.